# ¿Cómo puedo poner una tabla a lado de una imagen? O viceversa

Tags: latex

He estado intentando lograr este acomodo en el documento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que se pueden poner 2 o más imágenes, una a lado de la otra usando:

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}...
```

Pero no encontré ninguna forma en la que se pueda lograr poner una tabla a lado de una imagen, o viceversa. ¿Existe alguna forma?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850/49683

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar \begin{figure}[h]  y en su cuerpo puedes poner todas las imagenes que quieras, pero no demasiadas...

```
\begin{figure}[h]       
    \fbox{\includegraphics{image1.png}}   
    \hspace{20px}
    \fbox{\includegraphics{image2.png}}
    \hspace{20px}
    \fbox{\includegraphics{image3.png}}
    \caption{descripcion}
\end{figure}
```